# Import zxing into an existing project

Tags: android

I attempted to import ZXing into an android app that I am currently developing, but whenever I try to launch the activity, it crashes.

```
 public void bcreader(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
       if (requestCode == 0) 
       {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
          {
             String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
             String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
             // Handle successful scan
          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
          {
             // Handle cancel
          }
       }
}
```

That there is my MainActivity with the ZXing source over on the left.
I followed [this](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) tutorial but to no avail.
I've made sure that all of the files have been imported and the com.google.zxing... is set as a library etc.
I've also ensured that the manifest.xml has the appropriate permissions granted.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Error Log:
10-30 00:26:06.919: D/AndroidRuntime(4194): Shutting down VM
10-30 00:26:06.919: W/dalvikvm(4194): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a261f8)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.google.zxing.client.android/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
10-30 00:26:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     ... 11 more
10-30 00:29:27.799: D/AndroidRuntime(4407): Shutting down VM
10-30 00:29:27.799: W/dalvikvm(4407): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a261f8)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.google.zxing.client.android/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
10-30 00:29:27.799: E/AndroidRuntime(4407):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 1):

Add the following into the manifest.

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```